# Generated code is not picked up by the compiler

Tags: c#, .net, sourcegenerators

I have a source generator like this:

```
    [Generator]
    public class BuilderGenerator : ISourceGenerator
    {
        public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
            var code = @"
            namespace Generator
            {
                public class Builder<T>
                {
                    protected T _instance;

                    public T Build()
                    {
                        return _instance;
                    }
                }
            }
";
            context.RegisterForPostInitialization(ctx => ctx.AddSource("Builder.g.cs", code));
        }

        public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
        {
            
        }
    }
```

I am using this code generator in a console app project by referencing the code generator project. In the console app project I can see the code is generated in my IDE:

[image: IDE Screenshot]

Then I use the generated code in a class in console app project like this:

```
// Test.cs

using Generator;

namespace ConsoleApp;
public class Person
{
    
}

public class PersonBuilder : Builder<Person>
{
    
}
```

But when I compile the solution I get this error:

```
  Test.cs(1, 7): [CS0246] The type or namespace name 'Generator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
  Test.cs(9, 30): [CS0246] The type or namespace name 'Builder<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: What type of IDE are you using? I've tried with VS2022 and it seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Does this also happen when you run "dotnet build" from the terminal?